# jQuery Filter Two Arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

This code validates a set of form elements,

```
var objects = $(".validated").filter(function (){
    return $(this).val() == '';
});
```

Is there i could also filter for a length of >10, for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either chain together another filter, or modify the condition.

```
var objects = $(".validated").filter(function (){
    return $(this).val() == '' || $(this).val().length > 10;
});
```

Alternatively

```
var objects = $(".validated").filter(function (){
    return $(this).val() == '';
}).filter(function(){
    return $(this).val().length > 10;
});
```

Comment: My first example was wrong, but the second should have worked. You do understand that you're asking to get all elements that are either empty or over 10 characters, right?

Comment: Seems to me like you might be looking to grab all elements that AREN'T empty and are LESS THAN 10 characters. Am I corredt?